# How to get NMEA from the GPS Device?

Tags: gps, nmea

im trying to read the current position of GPS Device...using N95 from Nokia.
I read tht i will need my device to return the NMEA lines to the serialport and then i will parse/split it to get things I want but all along I dont know what to write to the serialport to make device return the NMEA ?

Like There are other commands of AT for messaging etc...Is there any specific command to send to serialport to get NMEA ???

Comment: Does this question really have anything to do with C#?

Comment: because im making a windows appl in c#

Comment: That doesn't really affect the answers to your specific question though, so I've removed that tag and added some more relevant ones.

Comment: Based on your comments below you should update the question, specifying WinMobile version etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found this site [site](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/10/22/how-to-share-the-gps-in-your-n95-with-your-laptop-via-bluetooth-in-linux/) which seems to guide you through everything you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it works in the N95, but in my HTC phone you cannot send commands to the GPS device to have it behave in a certain manner. Once I am connected to the serial port that the GPS device uses I can read a stream of data coming from it, which happens to be NMEA data. There is no way that I have found to send commands to the device to tell it how to behave.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that specific GPS device before, but for mine, I just have to open the port and I start receiving the NMEA data immediately.

Comment: Its a mobile phone...with a GPS option in it.there must be some way to make it send the coordinates in form of NMEA

Answer (score 0):

I have an N82, and as far as I know it doesn't speak NMEA directly. I use a script from [this page](http://gagravarr.org/code/) - specifically one the titled "# Turn your S60 phone with an internal GPS (eg your N95) into a Bluetooth GPS" - to get NMEA strings.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh oki so I need to run some script.Oki I think i should buy a specific GPS Device for it.

Which device will do my job in cheapest manner ?

Comment: Don't use answers to ask more questions, comment on or edit your original question, or ask a fresh question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked specifically with the N95, but most GPS devices will just start spitting out NMEA as soon as they're powered up, regardless of whether or not they have a lock. I don't know how the N95 is designed, but I'll bet it probably wasn't designed to give you access to the raw NMEA data from the GPS. You'll probably need some pretty fancy trickery to get it to do that.

If you don't need to use the N95, you might find it easier to just get a GPS module and use that instead. I've always purchased mine from SparkFun. They have some good [evaluation boards](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/categories.php?c=86) boards and [tutorials](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=68) to help you get started.

Comment: Whats diff btw a device and module ?

Comment: No difference. Device = module.

Answer (score 0):

A great way of doing this in Java ME is to use [JSR 179: the Location API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=179).  Your app needs to create an implementation of LocationListener, then set it on the default LocationProvider.  When your listener's locationUpdated method gets called, call:

```
location.getExtraInfo("application/X-jsr179-location-nmea");
```

This will provide access to the NMEA sentences.

You can send this over a serial port by using the Java ME commports mechanism (use:

```
System.getProperty("microedition.commports");
```

as described [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/properties/)).

Hope this helps,

funkybro